# What does 缀 mean in 浆果密密地缀在灌木丛中 (from "Fog Magic" 穿越魔雾)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From the children's novel 穿越魔雾 ("Fog Magic", page 18), I don't understand the part in bold below:

> [image: photo of page]
>
> ”我刚刚应该是见到了西米恩老人，而且知道了他住在哪儿。这场大雾可真是有魔法呢。“她一边哼着小曲，一边穿过开阔的牧场。**浆果密密地缀在灌木丛中**，格丽塔停下脚步采了一会儿。等她走到这片空地另一头时，已经摘了三分之一桶的浆果。

I get the overall idea that 格丽塔 (Greta?) is contemplating the magic fog, and filling her bucket with berries.  But I don't know how to understand this one part:

> 浆果密密地缀在灌木丛中
> berries [浆果] are densely [密密地] [verb] [缀] in the [在……中] shrubbery [灌木丛].

In particular, I don't understand what 缀 means here.  I'm guessing it's pronounced zhuì​ (and not chuò), and thus has one of the following meanings:​

> 缀 (zhuì)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%BC%80): to sew / to stitch together / to combine / to link / to connect / to put words together / to compose / to embellish

So something like "string together", I'm not sure this is how berries grow on bushes.

**Question**: What does 缀 mean in 浆果密密地缀在灌木丛中?

Comment: Quote: "I'm not sure this is how berries grow on bushes" -- It is not how they grow, it is how they looked like. If I wrote, "the moon is hanging in the sky". Does it mean it is actually hanging there? It is just an impression

Comment: perhaps interwoven? like, the berries arent superficial, it takes some effort to extricate them from the bushes

Comment: I agree with Tang Ho, it is a figure of speech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 浆果密密地缀在灌木丛中

缀(zhuì) here means 点缀, ***to decorate*** or ***to interperse***.

Compare to this example below:

> embellish a dress with lace and ribbons; // 用花边和丝带点缀衣装.

Answer (score 1):

缀 is an action of sewing or stitching, of course it's action by a human supposingly. The usage of this word here in the passage, it is called 比拟, a rhetorical way of describing: in this case, how the berries are entangled, as they were sewn onto the shrubbery.